# Copy file in batch script?

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a folder called HUD and it needs to go to `c:/.../Steam/`.

Can't find how I need to do it.

This is my script:

```
@echo off
title[*] Yannick's Gui's installer
:a:
echo [*] Yannick's Gui's installer
echo [*] Welcome %username%
echo [*] %username% Je Kan kiezen uit deeze optie's

ECHO --------------------------------
ECHO 1.Install HUD
ECHO 2.Delete HUD
Echo 2.Close
ECHO --------------------------------


CHOICE /C 123 /M "Optie?:"

IF ERRORLEVEL 5 GOTO ins
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO del
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO exit

xcopy "%~d0%~p0hud" C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\custom\ /c /d /e /h /i /k /q /r /s /x /y

:ins
xcopy "%~d0%~p0hud" C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\custom\ /e
pause

:del
del C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\custom\hud
GOTO End

:exit
close
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around paths that have spaces in them, so that windows knows it's a single parameter.

So:

`xcopy "%~d0%~p0hud" C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\custom\ /c /d /e /h /i /k /q /r /s /x /y`

Should be like:

`xcopy "%~d0%~p0hud" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\custom\" /c /d /e /h /i /k /q /r /s /x /y`